# How do I filter report from Apex including detail rows?

Tags: reporting, reports-api, detail

I [follow the documentation about filtering a report on a fly](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_analytics_filter_reports.htm) and try to get the detail rows by setting

```
reportMd.setHasDetailRows(true);
```

however, this doesn't work and the run report results return Reports.ReportFactWithSummaries instead of Reports.ReportFactWithDetails and I can't get the detail rows.

```
// Get the report ID
List <Report> reportList = [SELECT Id,DeveloperName FROM Report where 
    DeveloperName = 'MyReport'];
String reportId = reportList[0].Id;
 
Reports.ReportDescribeResult describe = Reports.ReportManager.describeReport(reportId);
Reports.ReportMetadata reportMd = describe.getReportMetadata();
reportMd.getReportFilters()[3].setValue('0061j00000Gg3C2AAJ');

reportMd.getReportFilters().add(new Reports.ReportFilter('OPPORTUNITY_ID', 'equals', '0061j00000Gg3C2AAJ') );
 
reportMd.setHasDetailRows(true);
// Run a report synchronously
Reports.reportResults results = Reports.ReportManager.runReport(reportId, reportMd);

/* Exception at this line since 
run report results return Reports.ReportFactWithSummaries instead of Reports.ReportFactWithDetails

Reports.ReportFactWithDetails factDetails = (Reports.ReportFactWithDetails) results.getFactMap().values()[0];
System.debug( factDetails );
*/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The third parameter `includeDetails` should be used and set to `true`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_reports_reportmanager.htm#apex_class_reports_reportmanager) for this to happen.

```
// Get the report ID
List <Report> reportList = [SELECT Id,DeveloperName FROM Report where 
    DeveloperName = 'MyReport'];
String reportId = reportList[0].Id;
 
Reports.ReportDescribeResult describe = Reports.ReportManager.describeReport(reportId);
Reports.ReportMetadata reportMd = describe.getReportMetadata();
reportMd.getReportFilters()[3].setValue('0061j00000Gg3C2AAJ');

reportMd.getReportFilters().add(new Reports.ReportFilter('OPPORTUNITY_ID', 'equals', '0061j00000Gg3C2AAJ') );
 
// Run a report synchronously
Reports.reportResults results = Reports.ReportManager.runReport(reportId, reportMd, true);
```

Comment: appreciate the self-answered questions -- you no doubt were stuck for a while, then figured it out and this Q&A benefits the Community

Comment: yeah, exactly...